# How can i do Asynctask in ListView illegal start

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask

I want to add listview but i get error . how can i do it ??Only listview and all https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users add users

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);




    txtResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_result);
    btnItemList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_item_list);



   /* btnItemList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new GetItemListTask().execute();
        }
    });
}*/
public void populateListView(ArrayList<String> myData){

    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    //Creating an array adapter and populating it with data fetched in Async task i.e. myData
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            (List<String>) new GetItemListTask().execute());

    myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


private void setResult(Post post) {
    txtResult.setText(post.getName());
}

private void setResult(ArrayList<Post> posts) {
    for (Post post : posts) {
        txtResult.append(post.getName());
    }
}



private class GetItemListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        ArrayList<Post> posts = new Gson().fromJson(s,
                new TypeToken<ArrayList<Post>>() {
                }.getType());
        setResult(posts);
    }
}
```

}

My image and error
[image]

Your advice important for me

Comment: didn't understand your question

Comment: I want to add listview but I want to delete my button

Comment: you want to remove button action and call async task outside of button?

Comment: did my answer help ?

Comment: Sorry your answer i dont understand and now i dont add listview

Answer (score 0):

Calling Async task in activity can be done

It depend on where you are going to call it, since you run asyn task when user press a button you can call it on OnCreate() or anywhere else.

1.

```
new GetItemTask().execute();`
```

2.

```
.post(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {

                       new GetItemTask().execute();
                       }
                    });
```